# Did rockets use turbopumps prior to the V-2?

Tags: rockets, turbopump, fuel

Did the liquid propellant rockets before [V-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-2_rocket) use [turbopumps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbopump) or were their fuel tanks pressurized with gas? Or perhaps were their engines gravity-fed?

Answer (score 8):

Goddard's first liquid fueled rocket in 1926 was pressure fed -- the engine was above the tanks, so gravity feed was not feasible. [Liquid oxygen was vaporized with a small alcohol burner](https://www.aps.org/publications/apsnews/200103/history.cfm), and the resulting oxygen gas pressurized both the LOX and gasoline into the combustion chamber.

The V2 is claimed to have [the first "large rocket engine" to use a turbopump](https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/v-2-rocket-engine-turbopump-cutaway/nasm_A19790951000), produced starting in 1942, but [von Braun was working on turbopumps from 1935](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbopump#Early_development). The V-2's immediate predecessors, the [1936 A-3 rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregat_(rocket_family)#A3) and [1938 A-5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregat_(rocket_family)#A-5_(1938%E2%80%931942)), were both pressure fed.

I don't think any "serious" rockets were ever flown with gravity-fed engines. Pressure-fed systems are fairly easy to manage (witness Goddard), and vastly increase the potential power of a rocket engine.

Comment: All three predecessors of the A-4 (V-2), the A-1, A-2 and A-3 were pressure fed.

Answer (score 4):

There are some problems with gravity fed engines:

- Chamber pressure must be low.
- Feeding pressure increases with acceleration.
- Rockets should be tall to increase pressure.
- Pressure decreases when tanks are discharged.
- Short experimental rockets are impossible.
- Gravity feeding may cause combustion instabilities.

All three predecessors of the A-4 (V-2), the A-1, A-2 and A-3 as well as the A-5 were pressure fed.

Comment: As propellant is consumed (reducing tank pressure), rocket mass decreases, increasing acceleration, which increases engine inlet pressure, so those two factors will tend to cancel out over a large part of the burn.